# How to use store procedure for custom paging in .NET core using EF Core db First approach?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, .net-core, pagination, entity-framework-core

I am new to C# and I am trying to learn new things regarding .NET Core.

I am having some problems making a store procedure for custom paging and then using it in .NET Core using Entity Framework Core.

I would be helpful if someone could give me a guidance.

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[GetAllUsers]  
@PageNo INT ,  
@PageSize INT ,  
@SortOrder VARCHAR(200)  
As  
Begin  
  
    Select * From   (Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (  
    Order by EmployeeId ) AS 'RowNum', *  
         from   [user]  
        )
        t  where t.RowNum Between ((@PageNo-1)*@PageSize +1) AND (@PageNo*@PageSize)  
        
End
```

this is my store procedure for custom paging
I will be using angular on the front end to show the paging

Comment: EF does not work with SPs. You have to use RawSql to invoke the SP.

Comment: Please share with us a bit more details. How does your stored procedure look like? How do you try to call it from EF Core? What is the expected behaviour and what is the observed?

Comment: SqlParameter studentID = new SqlParameter("@StudentID ", 1);
SchoolDBContext dbContext= new SchoolDBContext ();
List<Student> StudentList= dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("StudentsSP @StudentID", studentID).ToList();